# How do I append multiple variables to a url using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, url

I am having trouble appending multiple variables to the end of a url using javascript.  The user provides input on the page using a select menu and textarea.  Using just the textarea works, but I’m not able to include the select menu.

```
<?php
$price = $_GET['price'];
$title = $_GET['title'];
$retailer = $_GET['retailer'];
$img = $_GET['img'];
$link = $_GET['link'];
$desc = $_GET['desc'];    
?>

<textarea rows="3" id="textarea" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Size, color, style, etc" name ="options"></textarea>

<select style="width: 130px;" id="quantity" class="span2">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>

<script language="javascript">
    function test()
{
    var val=document.getElementById("textarea").value;  
    var val=document.getElementById("quantity").value; 
    var hrf="viewcart.php?retailer=<?php echo $retailer?>&link=<?php echo $link; ?>&price=<?php echo $price; ?>&title=<?php echo $title; ?>&options="+val;
    document.getElementById("a_link").href=hrf;
}
</script>

<a href ="#" id="a_link" onclick="test();" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
    <i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-white"></i>  Add to Cart
</a>
```

The line I am trying to alter is:

```
    var hrf="viewcart.php?retailer=<?php echo $retailer?>&link=<?php echo $link; ?>&price=<?php echo $price; ?>&title=<?php echo $title; ?>&options="+val;
```

I tried to have the below but it didn’t work:

```
    var hrf="viewcart.php?retailer=<?php echo $retailer?>&link=<?php echo $link; ?>&price=<?php echo $price; ?>&title=<?php echo $title; ?>&options="+val + “&quantity=” + quantity;
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work?

Comment: Where are you defining the variables?

Comment: What is the desired URL that you want to generate? Your current code will take the value from the `select` and append it to option. Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: You are defining the `val` variable twice; to what purpose?

Comment: Why are you using an A element where you shouldn't? The [type attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#attr-hyperlink-type) is supposed to be the MIME type of the linked resource, the value `submit` is meant for the type attribute of input elements. Use a styled span or similar element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this buddy,

```
var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").options[document.getElementById("quantity").selectedIndex].value;

var val=document.getElementById("textarea").value;

var hrf="viewcart.php?retailer=<?php echo $retailer?>&link=<?php echo $link; ?>&price=<?php echo $price; ?>&title=<?php echo $title; ?>&options="+val + “&quantity=” + quantity;
```

Comment: Same as mine, but nice to see it all in one line. +1

Answer (score -1):

You can't access the selected option of a dropdown using `value`. You have to find which option is selected and then what that option's value is.  Try this:

```
var selected_qty = document.getElementById("quantity").selectedIndex;
var all_qtys     = document.getElementById("quantity").options;

var quantity = all_qtys[selected_qty].value;
```

Comment: -1 The [value](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-select-element) of a select element is the value of the first selected option, or empty string if none are selected.

Comment: Really, because my code works, and the OPs doesn't.  And by the way, -1 to you for being a johnny-on-the-spot, sending the working draft spec of HTML5, while I was basing my answer on the [Recommended standard of html 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.6).  So stick your -1 up your selected value.

Comment: Your first two sentences are wrong. The relevant **standard** is the W3C DOM 2 HTML spec, which specifies the value of an [HTMLSelectElement's value property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-94282980), which is the basis of the statements in the HTML5 spec (which says almost exactly the same thing). The HTML 4 specification is about HTML, not the DOM. An HTML select element doesn't have a value attribute, but a DOM *HTMLSelectElement* has a value **property** (see DOM 2 HTML and HTML5 specs).